# Why can't I access items in json array?

Tags: mysql, react-native, aws-lambda, pymysql

I'm building an app in React-Native and I am using some code to connect to a MySQL RDS on AWS and am returning the results as a json array from a Lambda function to my mobile app to use the data for some other functions.

The relevant part of the code in the Lambda is:

```
    search_sql = f"SELECT * FROM Games"
    cur.execute(search_sql)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
                
    result = []
    for row in rows:
        d = {}
        for i, col in enumerate(cur.description):
            d[col[0]] = row[i]
            result.append(d)
    json_result = json.dumps(result)
    print (json_result)
    return json_result
```

The problem I am having is that even though the returned result looks correct using the AWS testing tools, when I used my app the console.log() I do of the result gives the response: [object Object].

In the AWS testing console it shows that what is returned looks like:

```
    "[{\"gameId\": 4, \"gameOwnerId\": 7, \"gameTypeId\": 2, \"numberOfSpaces\": 4},
    {\"gameId\": 5, \"gameOwnerId\": 5, \"gameTypeId\": 2, \"numberOfSpaces\": 3}]
```

So I know that what is being returned/ sent back to the app looks right but I must be doing something wrong with how I'm handling it at the other end.

Trying any of the below just gives the result [object Object] either as an alert or printed. I have no idea why.

(result) => alert(JSON.parse(result));

(result) => console.log(JSON.parse(result));

(result) => alert(JSON.parse(result[0]));

(result) => console.log(JSON.parse(result[0]));

Comment: I don't think you should return `json_result`. You should return the `result` list, because the framework is converting that to JSON automatically.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've tried this now but I'm having a different issue from this. Now if I use: .then((result) => alert(JSON.parse(result))) I get [object Object], [object Object], [object Object] repeteadly. But if I use alert(JSON.parse(result[0]))) it's giving the error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected end of input. Any idea why?

Comment: Actually never mind, just realised I should be using data for the console.log's and the alerts not the result. Thanks.

Comment: `alert(result)`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to serialize the list of objects into JSON format and include the mime type for the JSON response:

```py
def get_json(event, context):
    search_sql = f"SELECT * FROM Games"
    cur.execute(search_sql)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
                
    result = []
    for row in rows:
        d = {}
        for i, col in enumerate(cur.description):
            d[col[0]] = row[i]
            result.append(d)

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": json.dumps({
           "results": result
        })
    }
    return response
```